# Connect Oracle Database from docker container to node.js server

Tags: sql, oracle, docker, docker-container, node-oracledb

I have an Oracle Express Database inside a Docker container with ports mapping: 1521:1521 and 5500:5500. I am trying to connect to the database throw a Node.js server.
This is the server.js code:

```
    const express = require('express');
    const oracledb = require('oracledb');
    const cors = require('cors');
    const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
    const pdfParser = require('pdf-parse');
    const appRoute = require('./routes/route.js')

    const app = express();
    const dbConfig = {
        user: 'PDB_ADMIN',
        password: 'admin',
        connectString: 'localhost:1521/APP_PDB',
    };

    oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig, (err, connection) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
            return;
        }
        console.log('Connected to Oracle Database');

        const sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM JUDETE";

        connection.execute(sql, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err.message);
                return;
            }

            console.log(result.rows); // Log the retrieved rows

            connection.close((err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err.message);
                }
                console.log('Disconnected from Oracle Database');
            });
        });
    });

    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(fileUpload());
    app.use("/", express.static("public"));
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        next();
    });

    app.use('/api', appRoute);

    app.listen(8080, () => {
        console.log(`Server running on port 8080`)
    });
```

The Judete table has 42 record that have been inserted via sql developer, but the sql query inside server.js is returning 0.
If I try another query related to the judete table like:

```
"SELECT column_name, data_type, data_length, nullable
FROM all_tab_columns
WHERE table_name = 'JUDETE';"
```

It returns the correct data.
Why is this happening I am running out of ideas and time with this error.

...............................................

Comment: Never mind apparently I forgot to COMMIT the last changes I made to the database when I inserted the records. :)
Don't forget to commit your changes.